# using VBA IE automation to select text box

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using Access VBA to open Internet Explorer and fill out a form on a website.
This form has id of auto number which changes every so often but "_id" as per below is always the same, and I'm not sure if or how I can use the "_id" to insert the value into that field

this is what i have so far, thanks Tim
im not sure how exactly this site works as im fairly new here but this is what i have so far, one last question on Radio Buttons

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim url As String
Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument ' html object lib
Dim htmlInputElemen As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim htmlElementCol As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

url = www.abc.com
ie.navigate url
‘ this is for text box
Set htmlDoc = ie.Document
Set htmlElementCol = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
    For Each htmlInputElemen In htmlElementCol
        If htmlInputElemen.getAttribute("title") = "myTitle" Then
            htmlInputElemen.Value =  “myTitle”
'       ElseIf htmlInputElemen.getAttribute("title") = "myTitle2" Then
            htmlInputElemen.Value = “myTitle2”
        End If
   Next htmlInputElemen
‘ this is for combo box
Set htmlElementCol = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("select")
Dim htmlSelectElem As MSHTML.HTMLSelectElement
    For Each htmlSelectElem In htmlElementCol
        If htmlSelectElem.getAttribute("title") = "myComboBox" Then
            htmlSelectElem.Value = “myComboBoxValue”
        End If
    Next htmlSelectElem

‘now I have radio buttons which im not sure how to click using title, any ideas?
I tried this but no luck
Set htmlElementCol = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")
Dim htmlSpanElem As MSHTML.HTMLSpanElement
    For Each htmlSpanElem In htmlElementCol
        If htmlSpanElem.getAttribute("title") =  “ABC” Then
            htmlSpanElem.Click
        End If
    Next htmlSpanElem

<span class="ms-RadioText" title="ABC">
<input id="234sd87s89df">
<label for="234sd87s89df ">ABC</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim inputs, el

Set inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each el In inputs
    If el.getAttribute("_id") = "R_Destination" Then
        el.Value = "myValue"
        Exit For
    End If
Next el
```

EDIT: here's the same code refactored as a function

```
Function GetElement(doc as object, tagName As String, attrName As String, _
                                      attrValue As String) As Object
    Dim rv As Object
    Dim elements, element

    Set inputs = doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName)

    For Each element In elements
        If element.getAttribute(attrName) = attrValue Then
            Set rv = element
            Exit For
        End If
    Next element

    Set GetElement = rv

End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim el
Set el = GetElement(document, "input", "_id", "R_Destination")
if not el is nothing then el.value = "myValue"
```

Comment: Please give a bit more information as to what you mean by "multiple fields" - different types of tags?  different `id`s, but still input tags?  something else?